# Woocommerce: Reduce Stock condition

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, checkout

I use the plugin WC checkout-add-on that add meta data to WC order.

When saving order i want to add conditional logic on stock reduce process.

But i don't know how to retreive this WC Checkout add-on values in the condition:

```
function wcs_do_not_reduce_renewal_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {

     $addvalue= check_if_my_order_contains_a_specific_WC_checkout_add-on_value() ;

if ($addvalue=="achat-1")  {$reduce_stock = true;}
if ($addvalue=="achat-2")  {$reduce_stock = false;}
if ($addvalue!="achat-2" && $addvalue!="achat-1") {$reduce_stock = true;}
        return $reduce_stock;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock','wcs_do_not_reduce_renewal_stock', 10, 2 );
```

Thanks for help

Comment: yes you are right, sorry , i have updated, hope it's better...

Comment: anybody please ?